# How to install python2.7 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, python, dependencies

I'm trying to install Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04.
When I trype `python` or `python2` or `python2.7`, I get the following message:

```
 The program 'python' can be found in the following packages:
 * python-minimal
 * python3
 Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

After running `sudo apt install python2.7`, I get the following message but python is still unavailable when I type `python`.

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to
correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
mongodb-compass : Depends: gvfs-bin
                  Depends: python but it is not going to be installed     
python2.7 : Depends: python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3) but 
it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3) but   
it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. 
Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I also tried:

- `sudo apt install python`
- `sudo apt install python2.7`
- `sudo apt install python2`
- `sudo apt-get install python`
- `sudo apt-get install python 2.7`
- `sudo apt-get install python2`

Nothing have worked till now.

I can access Python3.5 by just typing `python3`, but I need python2.7.
I updated the repository before trying to install python. What am I doing wrong?

### Update

Running cache policy for python:

```
python2.7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3
  Version table:
     2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.7.11-7ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Running cache policy for mongodb:

```
mongodb-compass:
  Installed: 1.6.0-1
  Candidate: 1.6.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.0-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please update your question with output of `apt-cache policy python2.7`. It seems that you have PPAs or third-party repositories. In Trusty [`python2.7`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python2.7&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=trusty&section=all) is packaged normally.

Comment: You tagged question with 14.04 tag, but have Xenial repositories. I do not understand this. What is the output of `cat /etc/os-release` (add to question)?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using ubuntu 16.04. I edited my question

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy mongodb-compass`?

Comment: Try to remove it with `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-compass`. And retry python installation.

Comment: Need to find out why `libpython2.7-stdlib` won't be installed. Try installing it ans show us the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `mongodb-compass` with

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-compass
```

Then check that everything is in place with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get check
```

Comment: Does that mean I've to install mongodb-compass again?

Comment: You can install `mongodb-compass`  if you need it. I do not know its source.

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple command and get python 2.7 installed, thanks

sudo apt install python-minimal

and check the version you will get 2.7.X version  (python -V)